# How to improve image clarity in Unity 3d

Tags: unity

How to improve image clarity in Unity 3d. If we use same images for game developing in Adobe Flash and in Unity , flash game have more clarity , but in unity image will blur . Text Mesh also blur

How to get good clarity in unity games

I made a 2d game using quad,cube , sprite and Text Mesh . Platforms Android ,iPhone , Mac ,PC . Every platform have poor clarity

Image size is 44X44 pixels to 1024x1024 pixels